# QImage::format gives me QImage::Format_Invalid when running in console application

Tags: image, qt, console, format

I have a function that works perfect within a Qt application, but when called from a console application it fails. The function needs to verify an image file exists and can be read to a usable format:

```
void VerifyImageFormat(const QString& ImageFile)
{
    if (ImageFile.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }
    QFile file(ImageFile);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        QString Error("Failed to open image file ");
        Error += ImageFile;
        throw Error.toStdString();
    }

    if(QImage(ImageFile).format() == QImage::Format_Invalid)
    {
        QString Error(ImageFile);
        Error += " is of invalid image format.";
        throw Error.toStdString();
    }
}
```

I really need this functionality in my console application - what do I do?

Comment: What `QImage(ImageFile).isValid()` returns? Are you sure you can load the image? What is the image type: png, jpeg?

Comment: Do you link your console application with Qt Gui module?

Comment: First of all - thanks for the first and fast reply. It gave me the QImage::Format_Invalid so it throws the error below.

BUT the reason it happened is that somehow it seems something somewhere in the application I write over this file and it is empty, so the invalid format is for real :-(

Anyway - no issue here, sorry.

Oren